# What is the meaning of this sign { ${`expirydate`} } and how to use it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

there's a react component but i don't know how to use it .
and what is the meaning of this

```
<div className="f4InputCreditCardFrontExpiryDate" style={{ position: 'absolute ', bottom: 0 , right: 0}}>
  <span style={{
          color: 'white'
        }}>
          { `${expiryDate}` }
  </span>
</div>
```

how can i change the value of that expiryDate Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backticks (`) in ES6 specify a string template. A variable in the dollar sign `$` followed by curly braces `{}` designate the string value of that variable, to be formatted into the string.

It's easiest to illustrate with an example.

```
const a = 'world';
console.log(`hello ${a}`);  // hello world
```

The string formatting shown in your example is actually redundant as you can achieve the same output with just

```
{expiryDate}
```

since no other strings are being formatted in that template.

Comment: but what if i have a component and rendering it by 

<component />

how can i change that string template ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for by "change that string template." You can freely insert characters anwhere in the template outside of the dollar sign variable references.

Comment: scenario

there's an external component that has string template and i'm importing it to my project . how can change that string template on my project side if the component used as <component> </component>